# Describing Sub-activities with Call Behavior Actions

Tags: visual-studio-2013, uml, behavior

I created activity diagram D1. Then I created element "behavior" in the diagram D1. I also created activity diagram D2.
I choose Element Properties "behavior" link at the diagram D1.

When I hover the mouse over the "`Confirm Order`" behavior and double-click on it to transition to activity diagram D2 ("`ConfirmOrder.activity`") nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Product Visual Studio 2013

Comment: ![link to image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xILpq.png)

Comment: When I click on Confirm Order does not open chart ConfirmOrder.activity

Comment: You should tag your question accordingly.